# Building a minimal OS image

Tags: install, virtualization

Are there tools or guidelines for slimming an OSX installation down to the minimum needed to run particular applications? I would be interested in the case both with or without the GUI layer. A tool could be something like [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) for Windows.

Comment: Are you looking for the disk or the memory footprint? How big is a standard installation? And which size for a minimal image do you need to move forward?

Comment: @patrix: Both eliminating files to reduce storage and services to reduce RAM. No firm limit set yet on resources. Depends on the cost/benefit.

Comment: Without a clear goal and without an indication whether your constraint is disk space or RAM this question will be hard to answer. Also, what have you already tried yourself?

Comment: Let's firm up what you intend here. It depends heavily upon what specific version of a specific application you intend to run. For example, you could simply run the open-source darwin code to run ssh and bash. On the other hand, a purist might maintain that if you remove _anything_ from OS X, it's no longer OS X. In this case, the devil is in the details.

Comment: @bmike: You have become focused on a question other than what I asked. I want tools or guidelines for in general identifying parts of OS X that can be removed. I'm not asking for you to tell me how to solve a particular project.

Comment: Parts that can be removed depends on what you want it to do afterwards. For example, would removing the Safari from Installer package do it, or removing the fonts collection, ect.. you need to be more specific, shall it just come up with desktop, no Finder, No spotlight, no users switching, no Activity monitor, no Console, no......

Comment: Thanks for the edit to clarify your problem. There is an [meta] post on getting answers for software recommendations if this doesn't gain traction as currently worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 apps that I can think of that might do what you want, wile it is still unclear what you want.

The first one is called the [Pacifist](http://www.macworld.com/article/1165371/pacifist_makes_you_the_boss_of_file_archives_and_packages.html) and shows you a hierarchical (and searchable) list of every item contained therein in mavericks Installer package.

The second one is used to install customized Mavericks called UniBeast and MuliBeast.

[Here are the instructions how to use that.](http://www.tonymacx86.com/374-unibeast-install-os-x-mavericks-any-supported-intel-based-pc.html)

Comment: These look helpful, thanks. I have also found http://www.appzapper.com. I hope also to find some discussion of what facilities can be safely omitted.